# How can I save my installed packages on an external device so that i don't have to connect to internet on every new install

Tags: installation, package-management, offline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

I have a compac presario laptop. Whenever i try to install a new ubuntu my wireless driver (broadcom) does not get installed by default. I have to install it by using Additional driver.  For that i have to go to a internet cafe and connect it to a Lan.

That's really troublesome and i wonder if there is a way i can save my installed softwares like my drivers, Vlc,mp3 codecs .etc so that i don't have to connect to internet everytime i do a fresh install of Ubuntu.

Any help will be greatly appreciated .

Thanks and regards 
Kishlay Mishra

Comment: He's asked the same question here again: http://askubuntu.com/questions/170384/how-can-i-save-my-installed-packages-on-an-external-drive-so-that-i-can-do-an-of

Comment: @Kishlay - Please ask one Question One time only ,  it causes spam like situation :) . Help comes.

Comment: I used to use APTonCD until a few years back. http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Copy the packages from /var/cache/apt/archives onto something like a usb.

Open file manager in new installation as root, as soon as you have finished - close the file manager.

```
gksudo /var/cache/apt/archives
```

Copy them there.

Update from a terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Package should be there for you to use.